# Flutter play audio directly from binary data from socket

Tags: flutter, audio, websocket, binary, real-time

My app receive binary data from socket and need to decode binary data to audio and play realtime directly. i have searched and no library support play audio directly from binary stream realtime.

somebody have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to play audio bytes on certain platforms using [audioplayers plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers).
The BytesSource is currently available for Android (See [Feature Parity Table](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/blob/main/feature_parity_table.md)), while for other platforms one can use URI encoded bytes.
Use the workaround

```
UrlSource(Uri.dataFromBytes(bytes, mimeType: mimeType).toString())
```

found in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1269)

However, playing audio bytes does mean playing of bytes stream, so, one should implement buffering and maintain gapless playback.

Edit:
To play raw bytes, check [flutter_pcm_sound plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pcm_sound) out. Again, buffering is needed to play a stream.